# How to expand Variables inside a scriptblock prior to serialization

Tags: c#, powershell, serialization

I have a custom function that accepts a `[scriptblock]` parameter, The scriptblock is serailzed using `[System.Management.Automation.PSSerializer]::Serialize()` before it is sent to a remote process to be deserialized and invoked. The remote process does not have access to the local variables. I would like to allow the variables to be placed into the scriptblock on function call, however i would settle with a second parameter `$ArgumentList` to pass the arguments\parameters to the scriptblock. I browsed through `System.Management.Automation.dll` at `Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeCommandCommand` to see if i could determine how Invoke-command adds this functionality but i'm a beginner in C# and could't figure it out.

How can I expand the variables within the scriptblock before they are sent along their way?

An example of the local serialize function:

```
Function Send-Command
{
    param(
    [scriptblock]$Scriptblock
    )
    [String]$Serialized = [System.Management.Automation.PSSerializer]::Serialize($Scriptblock)
    [byte[]]$MessageBytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($Serialized)
    return $MessageBytes
}
```

And on the other end:

```
[byte[]]$Serialized = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString($MessageBytes)
[String]$Deserialized = [System.Management.Automation.PSSerializer]::Deserialize($Serialized.ToString())
return $Deserialized
```

I call the function with local variables:

```
$String = "This is a Test"

Send-Command -Scriptblock {Write-Output $String }
```

And on the other end:

```
Command: Write-Output $String
```

Should Output:

```
Command: Write-Output "This is a Test"
```

Comment: Are you saying, this is not working?

Comment: I edited my post, The remote shell can be a remote computer or just a separate process on the same device, it will not have access to the variables within my current scope. I need serialize the objects within the variables prior to sending them. Similar to how invoke-command works.

Answer (score 1):

Using PowerShell I would suggest te following:

Why don't you use **Invoke-Command** with the scriptblock to run the scriptblock on the remote computer? You can combine that both with the $**using**:*LocalVariableName* statement to access local variables from the remote host or with local variable expansion as described above, or even combine both.

I guess something like this should do the job:

```
    $ScriptBlock = {
        Write-Output $using:Text
    }
    $Text = 'This is a test'

    function Send-Command {
        param (
            [scriptblock] $ScriptBlock,
            [string] $ComputerName,
            [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential] $Credential
        )

        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computername -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock -Credential $Credential
    }

    $ComputerName = 'Server0123'
    $Credential = Get-Credential -Message "Enter credential for computer $($ComputerName)"
    Send-Command $ScriptBlock $ComputerName $Credential
```

[PowerShell: Invoke-Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command)

[PowerShell: about_remote_variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_variables)

Comment: That's a good idea, but sometimes you need to serialize a scriptblock to store it on disk to call it later. You could just create the script as a string and save it to a file, but what's the fun in that, also its horrible to double-escape strings.

Answer (score 1):

There's a way to deserialize a ScriptBlock.

You have to first create a scriptblock from the string.
Then you have to serialize all the variables that are bounded to the scope.
After it we use a regular expression to replace the variables with a payload to deserialize their values.

When the code is deserialized, it will have in the ScriptBlock an injected code to deserialize the value of the variables, so they retain the contents.
Then you need to call GetNewClosure() to unbound variables from the deserializer scope (any parameters for example), then they will be free to be bounded in the next call.

This solution is based on what the powershell DSC infraestructure does.

```bsh
Function Serialize-Command
{
    param(
        [scriptblock]$Scriptblock
    )
    $rxp = '\$using:(?<var>\w+)'
    $ssb = $Scriptblock.ToString()
    $cb = {
        $v = (Get-Variable -Name $args[0].Groups['var'] -ValueOnly)
        $ser = [System.Management.Automation.PSSerializer]::Serialize($v)
        "`$([System.Management.Automation.PSSerializer]::Deserialize('{0}'))" -f $ser
    }
    $sb = [RegEx]::Replace($ssb, $rxp, $cb, [System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::IgnoreCase)
    $Serialized = [System.Management.Automation.PSSerializer]::Serialize($sb)
    [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($Serialized)
}

Function Deserialize-Command
{
    param(
        [byte[]]$ScriptblockString
    )
    $Serialized = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString($ScriptblockString)
    $sb = [System.Management.Automation.PSSerializer]::Deserialize($Serialized.ToString())
    [Scriptblock]::Create($sb).GetNewClosure()
}
```

```bsh
$a = "is this what you wanted?"
$b = Serialize-Command { "test $using:a" }
$a = "okay"
$c = Deserialize-Command $b
$a = "right"


PS> & $c
is this what you wanted?
```

sources:

https://www.briantist.com/how-to/use-duplicate-dsc-script-resources-in-loop/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.scriptblock.getnewclosure?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0#System_Management_Automation_ScriptBlock_GetNewClosure

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/get-closure-with-getnewclosure/

Answer (score 0):

The three common ways to expands variables are the below:

```
$VariableName
"$VariableName"
$($VariableName)
```

... but there are other considerations depending on what you are doing.

Comment: That still does not change how variables are expanded, locally or remotely. Making a negative comment to my response without offering a more reasonable / more valid answer is not really helpful to the OP at all or anyone else who comes across this. So, not really sure why the downvote (but whatever - and I'd really like to see the moderators deal with this aspect. If one down votes without a valid new answer then down vote should be removed. IMHO), other than I missed comment on the use of the remote variable thing that Rogier caught and address.

Comment: This explains what should really be done https://www.briantist.com/how-to/use-duplicate-dsc-script-resources-in-loop/